# How to plot real time graphs in php or ajax or javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, ajax

I need a way to plot a real time graph which will use data from a database and update plot every second. Is there any way to do this and how? I tried using javascript but I am getting a memory error (the RAM keep building).

Comment: Post some code you have tried?

Comment: Have you looked into something like google charts? https://developers.google.com/chart/

Comment: yes I have tried but those charts are not real time.

Comment: I used http://www.jscharts.com/ the line plot

Comment: From the page I posted "Connect to your data in real time using a variety of data connection tools and protocols."

Answer (score 1):

Try [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update), they have a dynamic update chart.

Comment: The problem I have with all those graphs is that they use up all the RAM.

Comment: If you leave the chart open for long then the old data get pushed out and replaced by new data, but it is still in the memory. You can solve this by adding a custom javascript function called in every few mins to clean out that data from the chart which is not visible anymore, so it decreases memory usage.